# I want to import file from local storage to tinyMCE editor directly. Is it possible?

Tags: file-upload, tinymce, editor, tinymce-5

Step 1: Click on insert file Icon
[image]

Step 2: Click on Upload File button
[image]

Step 3: Select file from local storage
[image]

Step 4: After successfully uploading file will show on Step 3 panel then I have to select file from here to import on editor.
[image]

Step 5: Then file can be imported on editor.
[image]

How can I skip Step 2 and 4 to import file?  I want to import file from local storage to tinyMCE editor directly. Is it possible ?

I followed this documentation
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/configure/file-image-upload/

Answer (score 0):

try this in JS `script` tag

```
var editor_config = {
    path_absolute: "/",
    selector : "textarea:not(.mceNoEditor)",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern",
        "image code"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | addImage",
    setup: function(editor) { 
        editor.ui.registry.addButton('addImage', {
            text: 'Add Image', 
            icon: 'image', 
            onAction: function() {
                activeTextArea =
                    editor;
                $('#filePicker').css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
    },
    relative_urls: false,
    automatic_uploads: true,
    file_picker_types: 'image',


    file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

        input.onchange = function() {
            var file = this.files[0];

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function() {

                var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), {
                    title: file.name
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };

        input.click();
    },
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',




    init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
        jQuery(editor.getBody()).attr('aria-label', jQuery('label[for="' + editor.id + '"]').text());
    },
   

    file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: '/file-manager/tinymce',
            title: 'Laravel File Manager',
            width: window.innerWidth * 0.8,
            height: window.innerHeight * 0.8,
            resizable: 'yes',
            close_previous: 'no',
        }, {
            setUrl: function(url) {
                win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
            },
        });
    },
};

tinymce.init(editor_config);

$(function() {
    $(".fileSelection img").click(function(e) {
        activeTextArea.insertContent('&nbsp; <img src="' + $(this).attr("src") + '" /> &nbsp;');
        // $('#filePicker').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: To show insertfile button, needed to use tinydrive in plugin ,  but still now my problem is not fixed,  I want to import pdf file not image  and skip 2 and 4 no steps.  and also add image button is not working

Comment: https://codepen.io/tanvir-islam-the-decoder/pen/VwbNRNW?editors=0010